# Does $release-updates includes $release-security?

Tags: apt, repository

from the man page for `sources.list`:

```
The format for a sources.list entry using the deb and deb-src types is:
    deb [ options ] uri suite [component1] [component2] [...]
```

from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories, suite can be any of those value:

> `$release`: Don’t touch it, I like consistency, even with my bugs.
>
> `$release-security`: I’ll accept patches to existing versions (and very
>   rare version upgrades if absolutely necessary) in the process of
>   keeping my system secure.
>
> `$release-updates`: Okay, some bugs are worth
>   fixing, and I trust you this much (holds up two fingers like Maxwell
>   Smart).
>
> `$release-backports`: I have something akin to technology ADHD,
>   needing the latest of everything I can possibly get, but I can’t
>   handle running the development branch.
>
> `$devel`: I can take it.
>   Seriously. If you break my X, I shall become more powerful than you
>   could possibly imagine. I’ll file and maybe even fix the bugs and I’ll
>   do it even if power management is not so much ‘managed’ as vomited all
>   over the wall. Come get some.

My question is:

- Is every update included in the `$release-security` 
  included in the `$release-updates`?

further more:

- Is every update included in the `$release-updates` 
  included in the `$release-backports`?
- Is every update included in the `$release-backports` 
  included in the `$devel`?

Comment: Minor correction: `$devel` is actually called `$release-proposed`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At any given moment of time: No. (x3)

The channels are mutually exclusive. The `security` channels are fixes of the highest importance. The `updates` channels are for fixes that couldn't reach `security`, but still fixes of some sort. `backports` may contain bug fixes, but that is not their primary aim, and so it should not have anything in common with `security` or `updates`.

All packages go through `proposed` for testing before they reach `security`, `updates` or `backports`. For example `gnutls-2.12.23-12ubuntu2.1` reached `proposed` in [June](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/trusty-changes/2014-June/015589.html), and is now in [`security`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&keywords=gnutls).